# accumulating results during the execution of a std::for_each which gets interrupted by an exception

Tags: c++, std

I have a simple piece of code (`Checker`) which carries out some consistency checks on the elements of a vector (`pps`)

```
try{
    const Checker& results = std::for_each(pps.begin(), pps.end(), Checker());
    !results.diagnostic();
}
catch(std::bad_alloc&){
    cout << "the check operation failed: out of memory" << endl;
}
```

`Checker` has a member function (`diagnostic`) which outputs the results of this check.

The problem is: if for some reason (`std::bad_alloc`, for example) the check operation gets interrupted, i would like to have the already produced diagnostic available. Is it possible without recurring to a "substantial rewrite" allowing me to do something like:

```
Checker::Diagnostic diagnostic;
try{
    std::for_each(pps.begin(), pps.end(), Checker(diagnostic));
}
catch(std::bad_alloc&){
    cout << "the check operation failed: out of memory" << endl;
}
diagnostic.output();
```

This would look unnatural, since the return of std::for_each is intended for the exact purpose of being able to do such things, and the exceptional flow of control would dominate the look of the code.

Comment: The return of a function is intended for when the function completes, not when it does not complete. I don't find the second piece of code unnatural at all. Also binding a `const&` to the result of `for_each` is useless, just get it by value

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas of course the function would not return anything if interrupted. What I mean is: during the normal curse of operations everybody would expect to see the first form used. It looks natural and you immediately understand what is happening. The second version is not this "natural", so that you need to ask yourself what's happening. What I don't like is being driven by the exceptional curse of events in taking the decision to take a non-straightforward path.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas binding a const& to the result ensures that the result doesn't get copied. Am I wrong with some respect?

Comment: Yes, there is no copy being optimized in that statement, check [this](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas if I'm not wrong, there is no copy being optimized, assuming that the copy elision optimization is being applied. If this is not the case, the copy would be executed if there were not the const& thingy

Comment: There are two copies that are generally included under the umbrella of RVO, the copy done in the return statement, and the copy done in the calling function from the returned object to the destination object. That second copy is *always* optimized in all current compilers (gcc,clang,VS,AIX xlC,Solaris CC,comeau) and the optimization is derived directly from the calling conventions in the ABI (the caller allocates the object and passes a pointer). The compiler would need to do extra work to avoid optimizing that copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use the class like this:

```
Checker checker;
checker.doCheck(pps);
checker.diagnostic();
```

Or:

```
const Checker checker(pps);
checker.diagnostic();
```

That way, you can hide the details of the check in `doCheck()` (first example) or in the constructor (second example).

For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using ImportantItems = std::vector<int>;

class Checker {

public:

    Checker(const int criticalItem) : criticalItem(criticalItem) { }

    void doCheck(const ImportantItems& items)
    {
        accumulatedSum = 0;
        try {
            std::for_each(
                    items.begin(), items.end(), 
                    boost::bind(&Checker::performExtensiveCheckingOnAnItem, this, _1));
            this->dataOk = true;
        }
        catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
            this->dataOk = false;
        }
        std::cout << "AddAccumulated sum: " << accumulatedSum << std::endl;
    }

    void diagnostic() const
    {
        if (this->dataOk) {
            std::cout << "Everything was fine in last check" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Serious problems encountered" << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:

    void performExtensiveCheckingOnAnItem(const int anItem)
    {
        if (criticalItem == anItem) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Critical situation");
        }
        accumulatedSum += anItem;
    }

    const int criticalItem;
    int accumulatedSum{};
    bool dataOk{false};

};

int main()
{
    const int criticalItem(5);

    const ImportantItems importantItems{1, 2, 3, 4/*, criticalItem*/};

    Checker checker(criticalItem);
    checker.doCheck(importantItems);
    checker.diagnostic();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, althought I don't like making the checker class aware of the fact that it is being used on a container.

Comment: @StefanoFalasca May I ask why not?

Comment: well, it's not for very strong reasons, but the point is that Checker should be able to check a single element, therefore either I provide two checking methods (one for a single element, one for a range) or I implement it as I did. I think that in this situation it's clearer to use a for_each then it is to call a check(begin(...), end(...)). But it's just a matter of taste, I recognise this is subjective